# Twitter Bootsctrap load both bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking at the examples on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples.

They seem to load both bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css if I wanted to use responsive can I just load bootstrap-responsive.css or does it require both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load both. bootstrap-responsive.css only includes the required CSS changes (media queries) for smaller sizes while bootstrap.css includes the CSS that applies to all sizes.

And for production use the *-min.css counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

It requires both if you want it to be responsive.